# Dolbeault cohomology of complex manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold of dimension $n$ and let $D$ be a smooth hypersurface. Then the restriction map gives rise to a homomorphism in Dolbeault cohomology:
$$
\rho:H^{p,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)\rightarrow H^{p,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(X-D),
$$
when is this map injective?

Comment: Shouldn't the map fails to be injective exactly when Hartog's theorem fails?